# AutoLayout set height of UITableViewCell based on children

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to set the height of a UITableViewCell based on its children's constraints. Basically, here's the layout:

`UITableView` > `UITableViewCell` > `NestedUIView` (with a computable height)

I started by setting the top, bottom, left, and right constraints of the `NestedUIView` to be 10px off from the `UITableViewCell`. Then, I tried adding a height constraint (which in my head would force the `UITableViewCell` to expand to fit that content. Of course though, it causes a constraint conflict and fails.

This seems like it should be trivial, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 42;
```

This will tell the table to use the cell constraint's to determine the height.

Comment: Oddly enough, adding that code had zero effect. The conflict error still looks exactly the same.

Comment: Actually I just got it to work. I needed to apply the constraint to the cell's contentView instead of the cell itself. Makes sense.

Comment: Actually I'm now seeing that if I set the height too high (roughly > 200), it causes the error again. Any ideas?